# How to check Silent notification in urbanairship

Tags: background, push-notification, urbanairship.com, silent

I am implementing silent push notifications in iOS project.
How can I test a silent on the Urban Airship website?

What does the payload have to be?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a push without a badge, notification, and sound with `content available` checkbox checked in the iOS sub options.